# Accesing values inside of dynamically generated Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a large XML file that has been tormenting me. I have managed to work around many of the flaws in its design, and would like to transfer it to a python dictionary for later writing to SQL, etc. In the mean time, I can use the dictionary to finish my task.

Here is where the problem lies in my code:

```
import os, csv
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

dd = {}
x=0
with open('transactions.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    h = (reader.fieldnames)

    for row in reader:
        x+=1
        for i in h:
            dd[x] = {'date':row['Date'],
                    'amount':row[' Amount'],
                     'type':row[' Type'],
                     'note':row[' Description']
                     }
```

The idea is that I am reading file (in this case a practice one) and feeding it into a dictionary. There is one key with one entry as above. I can enumerate it and use that as the index, or I can manually count it. I can also use a unique field for dd[x]. But whatever I do, I cannot access the values inside of the dictionary individually.

For example, it would be great to do the following:

```
print (dd[25]['date'])
```

I am stopped cold every time. I would like to think that I could access entry 25 (dd[25]) and get the date (dd[25]['date']).

All of the examples I can find on nested dictionaries are manually constructed and do not address this problem I cannot seem to solve.

Please advise. Many Thanks!

Comment: What does any of this have to do with XML?  I think you meant "CSV".

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in reader:
    x+=1
    for i in h:
        dd[x] = {'date':row['Date'],
                'amount':row[' Amount'],
                 'type':row[' Type'],
                 'note':row[' Description']
                 ......
                 }
        for key in dd[x].keys():  ## iterate through keys
              print d[x][key]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you don't need to recreate a dictionary, the rows are already dicts:

```
import csv

dd = {}
with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    h = next(reader)

    for x, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        dd[x] = row


print(dd)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{1: {'Date': '4/30/16', 'Amount': '11.23', 'Type': '1', 'Description': 'Something 1'}, 2: {'Date': '4/30/16', 'Amount': '10.23', 'Type': '2', 'Description': 'Something 2'}, 3: {'Date': '4/30/16', 'Amount': '9.23', 'Type': '3', 'Description': 'Something 3'}, 4: {'Date': '4/30/16', 'Amount': '8.23', 'Type': '4', 'Description': 'Something 4'}}
```

Also worth noting, it seems appropriate to use a list instead since those are usually used for numerical contiguous indexed data